# PGFPlots - Make 'mark repeat' count actual data points, not just visible

Tags: pgfplots

In the following code I expect marks of both series to be on aligned on vertical lines:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        ymin = -10.5,
        mark repeat = 10,
        grid = both,
    ]
    \addplot+[blue, samples = 100] {x - 10};
    \addplot+[red,  samples = 100] {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

However, it looks like that:

[image]

So, **mark repeat** starts counting marks when they become visible. Can I make it to count actual data points? (Without hand-picking mark phase or mark indices.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. As far as I can see this can only be accomplished by using `clip=false`, but that of course brings an undesired side effect ... As far as Christian (the author of PGFPlots)  stated (via email), this behavior is intended. So I guess you have to use the `mark phase` key, which should not be a problem in this simple case to match the marks of both plots.

Comment: For the record: I have added a feature request to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/53/) for that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is merely a feature request.